# how to push local projects into under a remote repository

Tags: git, github, directory, project

I am new to github. I have 2 repositories in github name "ios" and "android". I have multiple projects for ios and android such as: ios-1, ios-2, android-1, android-2.
How do I push ios-1 and ios-2 from local to under remote ios repo? and android-1 and android-2 to under repo android.
Basically, I want my github is organized like this:

```
ios
    ios-1
    ios-2

android
    android-1
    android-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Clone the respective repositories to the desired location on your computer using the `git clone https://github.com/(username)/(repository name).git` command in the terminal. Once the files you want to push to Github are in their respective repositories, which are folders generated by the previous command, use the `git add .` command to add the files to the git index followed by `git commit -m"your message here"` to commit these new additions. Finally you can push your commits to the desired branch with the commands `git checkout -b (branch name)` which switches you to your desired branch and `git push origin (branch name)` which pushes your changes to the origin of the branch. The branch name will be master unless you have created other branches in your repository.

My answer above is not extremely in depth nor does it provide every possible git command you might need. It only provides the very basics for using Github in a  way which is perfect for simple single person projects. Linked below are fantastic resources that provide more detail as well as other commands and uses for Github that are beyond the basics I briefly outlined above.
https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/
https://dev.to/dhruv/essential-git-commands-every-developer-should-know-2fl